# Changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH has no effect when using Intel OneAPI in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hdf5, intel-fortran, intel-oneapi

I was trying to compile my code with Intel Fortran compiler in Ubuntu 20. My code needs HDF5 library, which I compiled separately, and I added the HDF5 library into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.After that, my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` looks like this:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/2021.9.0/env/../lib/intel64/gcc4.8:/opt/intel/oneapi/rkcommon/1.11.0/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/ospray_studio/0.12.0/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/ospray/2.11.0/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/openvkl/1.3.2/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/oidn/1.4.3/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.9.0//libfabric/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.9.0//lib/release:/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.9.0//lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.1.0/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/oneapi/itac/2021.9.0/slib:/opt/intel/oneapi/ispc/1.19.0/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/2021.8.0/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/oneapi/ippcp/2021.7.0/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/2021.8.0/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/oneapi/embree/4.0.1/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/dnnl/2023.1.0/cpu_dpcpp_gpu_dpcpp/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/debugger/2023.1.0/gdb/intel64/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/debugger/2023.1.0/libipt/intel64/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/debugger/2023.1.0/dep/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/dal/2023.1.0/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.1.0/linux/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.1.0/linux/lib/x64:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.1.0/linux/lib/oclfpga/host/linux64/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.1.0/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin:/opt/intel/oneapi/ccl/2021.9.0/lib/cpu_gpu_dpcpp:“:/home/samz/local/lib/phdf5/1.8.23/build_ifort_2021_impi_2021/lib”
```

[figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvQXh.png)

However, when I run my code, the Intel fortran compiler complains:

```
./****.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5_fortran.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Whereas `libhdf5_fortran.so.10` is in the `/home/samz/local/lib/phdf5/1.8.23/build_ifort_2021_impi_2021/lib` directory:

```
$ ls -la /home/samz/local/lib/phdf5/1.8.23/build_ifort_2021_impi_2021/lib
total 11420
drwxrwxr-x 2 samz samz    4096 Apr 10 14:35 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 samz samz    4096 Apr 10 14:35 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 samz samz 6763194 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 samz samz  419748 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5_fortran.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 samz samz    1115 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5_fortran.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 samz samz      25 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5_fortran.so -> libhdf5_fortran.so.10.0.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 samz samz      25 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5_fortran.so.10 -> libhdf5_fortran.so.10.0.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 samz samz  341456 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5_fortran.so.10.0.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 samz samz  229896 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5_hl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 samz samz      19 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5_hl_fortran.a -> libhdf5hl_fortran.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 samz samz  127576 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5hl_fortran.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 samz samz    1292 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5hl_fortran.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 samz samz      20 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5_hl_fortran.so -> libhdf5hl_fortran.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 samz samz      27 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5hl_fortran.so -> libhdf5hl_fortran.so.10.0.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 samz samz      27 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5hl_fortran.so.10 -> libhdf5hl_fortran.so.10.0.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 samz samz  106024 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5hl_fortran.so.10.0.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 samz samz    1080 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5_hl.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 samz samz      20 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5_hl.so -> libhdf5_hl.so.10.2.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 samz samz      20 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5_hl.so.10 -> libhdf5_hl.so.10.2.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 samz samz  163408 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5_hl.so.10.2.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 samz samz     983 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 samz samz    6699 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5.settings
lrwxrwxrwx 1 samz samz      17 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5.so -> libhdf5.so.10.4.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 samz samz      17 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5.so.10 -> libhdf5.so.10.4.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 samz samz 3491568 Apr 10 14:35 libhdf5.so.10.4.1
```

Then I used the option `export LD_DEBUG=all` to debug the problem and figured out the problem was that the added HDF5 library path is not actually checked. Here are the extracts from the output of the LD_DEBUG mode:

```
...
126670:  search path=/opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/2021.9.0/env/../lib/intel64/gcc4.8:/opt/intel/oneapi/rkcommon/1.11.0/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/ospray_studio/0.12.0/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/ospray/2.11.0/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/openvkl/1.3.2/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/oidn/1.4.3/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.9.0//libfabric/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.9.0//lib/release:/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.9.0//lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.1.0/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/oneapi/itac/2021.9.0/slib:/opt/intel/oneapi/ispc/1.19.0/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/2021.8.0/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/oneapi/ippcp/2021.7.0/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/oneapi/embree/4.0.1/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/dnnl/2023.1.0/cpu_dpcpp_gpu_dpcpp/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/debugger/2023.1.0/gdb/intel64/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/debugger/2023.1.0/dep/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/dal/2023.1.0/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.1.0/linux/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.1.0/linux/lib/x64:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.1.0/linux/lib/oclfpga/host/linux64/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.1.0/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin:/opt/intel/oneapi/ccl/2021.9.0/lib/cpu_gpu_dpcpp:“/tls/haswell/x86_64:“/tls/haswell:“/tls/x86_64:“/tls:“/haswell/x86_64:“/haswell:“/x86_64:“        (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
...
```

[figure2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbHrN.png)

I was able to work around by creating links to the HDF5 library at the directories that are actually checked by the code. But wondering why changing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH did not work?

I loaded the Intel environment in `.bashrc` via `. /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh > /dev/null`

Appreciate your helps. Thank you.

Comment: The libhdf5 library is not inside the oneAPI installation, there is no reason why the oneAPI environement should see it. Also, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for the runtime linker. Try adding the path to your library to `LIBRARY_PATH` or supplying the path using the `-L` flag.

Comment: @Vladimir F Героям слава Adding the path to your library to `LIBRARY_PATH` didn't help. The error happens when I run the program, not when I was linking it. Also I tried `./****.exe -L/home/samz/local/lib/phdf5/1.8.23/build_ifort_2021_impi_2021/lib` and it also didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right, it is a runtime error. In that case the things to use are indeed `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` together with `ldconfig`.

Comment: However, when I quickly glanced over the first snippet in your question, the one that defines `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, it seems to me you are doing it wrong. You should just use `:/home/samz/local/lib/phdf5/1.8.23/build_ifort_2021_impi_2021/lib` and not `:“:/home/samz/local/lib/phdf5/1.8.23/build_ifort_2021_impi_2021/lib”`. The double colon is not a part of the path.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Thank you very much! I think I have figured that out. You are right, the quotation mark is the problem. It is weird that in Mac I can do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HDF5_DIR/lib"`, but in Ubuntu I must do it without the quotation mark.